# SQL: Appending number of records from this month as a column/field

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm working with HiveQL trying to query Hadoop. My problem is this.

Let's say I have a query (and resulting table) like this:

```
SELECT CustomerID, PurchaseID, DateOfPurchase
FROM MyTableName;

+------------+------------+----------------+
| CustomerID | PurchaseID | DateOfPurchase |
+------------+------------+----------------+
|        101 |        501 | 2014-01-01     |
|        101 |        502 | 2014-01-15     |
|        101 |        503 | 2014-01-20     |
|        101 |        504 | 2015-01-19     |
|        101 |        505 | 2015-08-25     |
|        102 |        506 | 2014-01-02     |
|        102 |        507 | 2014-01-03     |
|        103 |        508 | 2016-05-05     |
+------------+------------+----------------+
```

I want to add another column that represents the number of orders a customer has made per month, corresponding with the date in each row. Here is my idea of the resulting table:

```
+------------+------------+----------------+--------------------+
| CustomerID | PurchaseID | DateOfPurchase | PurchasesThisMonth |
+------------+------------+----------------+--------------------+
|        101 |        501 | 2014-01-01     |                  3 |
|        101 |        502 | 2014-01-15     |                  3 |
|        101 |        503 | 2014-01-20     |                  3 |
|        101 |        504 | 2015-01-19     |                  1 |
|        101 |        505 | 2015-08-25     |                  1 |
|        102 |        506 | 2014-01-02     |                  2 |
|        102 |        507 | 2014-01-03     |                  2 |
|        103 |        508 | 2016-05-05     |                  1 |
+------------+------------+----------------+--------------------+
```

That is, for each row, the **PurchasesThisMonth** column represents how many purchases were made by that customer in that month. Customer 101 made 3 purchases in January of 2014, so each of the January 2014 rows have a 3 in **PurchasesThisMonth**.

**I was able to get this to work using an INNER JOIN on a subquery on the same table.** But this takes quite a while considering my dataset is quite large. However, **is there a better/faster way of doing this?**

Here is my bruteforce way of solving it.

```
SELECT CustomerID, PurchaseID, DateOfPurchase, Sub.PurchasesThisMonth
FROM MyTableName
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
    CustomerID, 
    COUNT(Inner.PurchaseID) as PurchasesThisMonth
    MONTH(Inner.DateOfPurchase) as month, 
    YEAR(Inner.DateOfPurchase) as year

    FROM MyTableName Inner
    GROUP BY Inner.CustomerID, 
             MONTH(Inner.DateOfPurchase), 
             YEAR(Inner.DateOfPurchase)
) Sub
ON CustomerID=Sub.CustomerID AND
   MONTH(DateOfPurchase)=Sub.month AND
   YEAR(DateOfPurchase)=Sub.year
```

This query makes an entire subquery on the exact same table. Is this necessary? If not, what is the best practice here?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't see that you could do it better.  Unless you could save the sub as a view.  don't know if hadoop can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use window function `count() over()`.

```
SELECT CustomerID, PurchaseID, DateOfPurchase
,count(*) over(partition by
               customerid,
               MONTH(DateOfPurchase), 
               YEAR(DateOfPurchase) order by customerid)
FROM MyTableName;
```

Comment: This reduced the time my query takes immensely. Thank you!